# Xamarin MVVMCross Alternatives

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

At the moment our company is using the `Xamarin` framework to create apps for `Android` and `IOS`.

We looked at `MVVMCross` for even more reusable code across the platforms. however the creating of platform specific views bothered us and we wanted to go further and created a shared xml file where we define the view for all platforms wherever that was possible.

These xml files are constructed like a XAML file which we then implement on the different platforms. for example

```
 <MapControl Width="100" />
```

converts to a MKMapView in `IOS` and a com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment on `Android` (just to give a rough example)

Anyway, my question is if anyone knows any opensource frameworks/ projects that implement a similar structure as stated above.

Perhaps this is even on the road map for `MVVMCross`?

Comment: you can look on Appercode.com, it's still in beta but may be suite your needs

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Within MVVMCross, there's the concept of "Plugins".

https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/MvvmCross-plugins

These plugins implement the native equivalent of whatever you're trying to use(Maps, Location, File, etc)

Many of these are made by the community or people who need certain implementations made for a project.

As for another solution, there is ReactiveUI which is another MVVM framework built on top of Xamarin as well(But not limited to)

https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI

Hope that helps!

Comment: MvvmCross also has the ability to infer the UI from a model and I believe there is some work taking place to allow developers to create UI in JSON which gets parsed into platform specific UIs. MvvmCross is immense IMO - the dialog stuff is great. The droid version of which isn't as polished as the touch version but still good.

Answer (score 4):

Now Xamarin has introduced what is called  "the Xamarin Forms" that you define the UI once and it will implement native UIs on different plat forms based on that xml form.