# Maximizing UI Code Reuse with Xamarin - MvvmCross?

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

I'm porting an existing iOS / Xamarin app to Android at the moment. All views and controllers are built extending native iOS classes (UIView / UIViewController) - which is standard with Xamarin development. My app is relatively simple, several UITableViews with custom table cells, Shinobi charts, Shinobi grids.

As we replatform the UI, I want to make sure I can reuse as much of the code as possible between Android and iOS.

Is MvvmCross the best way to do this? What are the viable alternatives to MvvmCross for reusing as much UI code as possible when building cross platform Xamarin apps?

Answer (score 0):

I actually asked a question a while ago which is closely related to this.

[Xamarin MVVMCross Alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20656250/xamarin-mvvmcross-alternatives)

Be sure to check out appercode.com which is mentioned in the first comment

http://appercode.com/eng/products/videos/